# <br /> tag seems to be the only way to vertically space a div within a form?

Tags: html, css

This is just weird to me and maybe I'm just missing something.

I'm laying out a form with a couple divs inserted at random spots and the spacing on the div places the text in the correct location, but the background-color appears way above the text.

Example:

(Unbroken)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp7lJ.jpg

(With 11 break tags)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVdxx.jpg

Here is the relevant code:

```
<div class="page" id="booking_columns">
    <div class="seven-hundred">
        <form class="booking_form">
            <div class="form_header">
                <h5><span class="spacer">Tell us about you</span></h5>
            </div>
            <p class="form_tags form_left">First Name</p>
            <p class="form_tags form_right">Last Name</p>
            <input type="text" class="customSelect_first_name" name="first_name">
            <input type="text" class="customSelect_last_name" name="last_name">
            <br />
            <p class="form_tags form_left">Email Address</p>
            <br />
            <input type="text" class="customSelect_email" name="email">
            <br />
            <p class="form_tags form_left">Phone Number</p>
            <br />
            <input type="text" class="customSelect_phone" name="phone">
            <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            <div class="form_header">
                <h5><span class="spacer">Tell us about your home</span></h5>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#booking_columns
{
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
}

.seven-hundred
{
    width:600px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;    
}

.booking_form
{
    position:relative;
}

.page
{
    width:900px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.form_header
{
    position:relative;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border:0;
    background-color:#EBEBEB;
    height:50px;
    width:580px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

Any idea why this is coming out like this? Better yet, any logical ways to correct this with 11 break tags?

Comment: And try using `label` tags instead of `p` tags.

Comment: If the problem is that without the `<br>`s, the background of the lower h5 is in the wrong position, I can't reproduce it. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zawyB/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not showing your whole CSS code aren't you? But as far as i can tell you might be using the classes `form_left` and `form_right` to float the elements left and right.
So maybe add a:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

right before the second form header.

Comment: Yep, completely forgot about clear:both.  Adding that to the div class fixed it.  Thanks a lot. =)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `clear:both` instead of `</br>` to align div vertically.

Comment: You were correct as well.  Unfortunately, you were both in at 18 minutes, I have no idea who was in first. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with your relative positioning also you are using same class for form header and footer

i have added new class form_footer

```
.form_footer
{
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
border:0;
background-color:#EBEBEB;
height:50px;
width:580px;
margin-top:100px;
}
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/d3c3P/1/)

Comment: @user1918000 updated the fiddle, sorry i posted the wrong fiddle first